# Pointer to pointer issue in C

Tags: c

This is what I'm trying to achieve.
Inside pointer 'r' I have the address of pointer 'p', now I try to move the value of 'p'(which is an address) using pointer arithmetic by calling function moveforward().
 I get this error :

```
void value not ignored as it ought to be
movingresult=moveforward(r);
```

What's wrong here? It's a bit complicated though dealing with pointer to pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void moveforward(int** y) {
     *y = *y+1;
     printf("value of *y in function : %p\n",*y);

}


int main () {
int a = 16;
int *p;
int **r;
p = &a;
r = &p;
int **movingresult;

printf("Value of p before moving :%p\n",p);
movingresult=moveforward(r);
printf("Value of p after moving :%p",movingresult);

return 0;

}
```

I just changed my code , so now it looks like this, everything runs well , but the result is not what i expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void moveforward(int** y) {
 *y = *y+1;
 printf("Value of *y now has been moved to : %p\n",*y);

}


int main () {
int a = 16;
int *p;
int **r;
p = &a;
r = &p;
int **movingresult;

printf("Value of p before moving :%p\n",p);
moveforward(r);
printf("Value of p after moving :%p\n",r);

return 0;

}

OUTPUT :
Value of p before moving :0x7fffa5a1c184
Value of *y now after moving : 0x7fffa5a1c188
Value of p after moving :0x7fffa5a1c178
```

MY EXPECTATION : the 'p' after moving must be equal to *y which is 0x7fffa5a1c188

Comment: `moveforward` is declared `void`.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I compile it. `main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:19:13: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
 movingresult=moveforward(r);
             ^

exit status 1`

Comment: @KenY-N I have changed my code above.

Comment: `printf("Address of p after moving :%p\n",r);` --> `printf("Address of p after moving :%p\n", p);` or `printf("Address of p after moving :%p\n",*r);`

Comment: Why are you talking about "address of p" changing? You mean, the value of p (which is an address).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY awsome! you solved my problem bro, tq.

Comment: @philipxy sorry, you're right, I should have said "the value of p".

Answer (score 2):

when you call the function moveforward, the pointer address of r not change.
moveforward(r);
after call moveforward, the address of r isnot change yet.
so if you execute 
printf("Value of p after moving :%p\n",r);

the address of r are still not change.

if you want get your expected value, you should do:
printf("Value of p after moving :%p\n",*r);

Answer (score 1):

**This is how things look before doing any pointer arithmetic.**

[image: This is how things look before moving the pointer]

After you execute **moveforward(r);**, this is how things look:

[image: After moving the pointer]

and these are the pointer values:

```
printf("Address pointed by p :%p\n",p); // Prints 0x7fffa5a1c188
printf("Address pointed by p :%p\n",*r); // Prints 0x7fffa5a1c188
printf("Address pointed by r :%p\n",r); // Prints 0x7fffa5a1c178
```

This is because, when you execute the following piece of code,

```
void moveforward(int** y) {
*y = *y+1;
printf("Value of *y now has been moved to : %p\n",*y);
}
```

Only the content of pointer p is incremented(0x7fffa5a1c184 to 0x7fffa5a1c188). But the content of pointer r (0x7fffa5a1c178) remains the same.